# Can the sum of continuous functions be discontinuous?

Tags: calculus, continuity

In reading my calculus 4 textbook about Fourier series, I get the quote:
"A remarkable fact about Fourier series is that the sum function $f(x)$ is not necessarily continuous even though the terms in the series are continuous."
How is this possible? Can someone give me an example? Or am I interpreting this wrong, and what it really means is that a function $f(x)$ can have a continuous Fourier series without $f$ itself needing to be continuous?

Comment: I cannot give you a rigorous explanation, you'll need to get that from someone else, but I can roughly outline it. Consider a box wave. A box wave is discontinuous, but it is still a periodic function and therefore has a Fourier series. If you can except that there is a series which increasingly flattens the peak of a sine wave while increasing magnitude of the slope before and after it flattens, without changing the amplitude, then the limit of the series will be a box wave.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An *infinite* sum of continuous functions can be discontinuous, yes.

Here's an example: Consider the *continuous* functions $f_k\colon\mathbb [0,1]\to\mathbb R$ given by $f_1(x)=x$ and $f_k(x)=x^k-x^{k-1}$ for $k>0$. The finite partial sums of this sequence of functions are
$$
F_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n f_k(x) = x+(x^2-x)+(x^3-x^2)+\cdots+(x^n-x^{n-1}) = x^n.
$$
However, the limit of this series of functions yields
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} F_n(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} x^n = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if $x\in[0,1)$,} \\ 1 & \text{if $x=1$}\end{cases},
$$
which is a discontinuous function on $[0,1]$.